# How to reverse all animations, physics and simulations?

Tags: rendering, animation, physics, smoke-simulation, motion-blur

I simply want to reverse EVERY animation, physic, motion blur etc. so that the scene is EXACTLY played and rendered backwards.

Is this possible?

I don't want to render my scene forward and use the VSE to put it in reverse, because I want to use motion blur, which looks odd when being reversed obviously. So, is there any way (without scripting for hours) to reverse everything, including physics, simulations and particle systems? Reversing only the motion blur would be okay as well (but I don't think that this is included as a feature by scratch), but not as great as reversing everything.

Thanks beforehand for taking some time to read through and provide help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the Video Sequencer Editor.

In the *Render* tab, scroll down to *Post Processing* and make sure *Sequencer* is checked.

[image]

Go to the VSE.

[image]

Click *Add* -> *Scene* -> *Scene*

In the VSE's *Properties* panel, scroll down to *Filter* and make sure *Reverse* is checked.

[image]

Go back to the default window layout (select *Default* where you selected *Video Editing* in the second step above), and render your animation.

During render, the original frame number will be displayed, counting down from the max to the min number. After render but before saving to file, the image will be passed through the VSE, and the file name will be changed appropriately.

As for the motion blur, it can be made to appear reversed by setting *Position* to *Start on Frame* and the *Shutter Curve* to fall from the upper left corner to the lower right corner.
Position defines when the shutter opens in relation to the frame's start time, and the shutter curve defines how it opens and closes. I also got slightly more pleasing results setting *Shutter Type* to *Top-Bottom* and *Rolling Shutter Duration* to a high value, though the difference is marginal.

[image]

The animation below moves the ball from the top left corner to the lower right corner, and was reversed by the above method to appear to move from the lower right to the top left.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out this/the next day and mark your answer as correct as soon as I get it to work. Appreciate your work on the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create your simulation and export all objects to alembic. Then you can reimport them. If you look into the constraints panel of your imported objects, you'll see that they came with a Transform Cache constraint.

All you need to do now is click "Override Frame" and keyframe the value to go backwards.

I tried it with cell fracture and a simple rigid body sim.
Smoke however, doesn't work that way. But at least this should get you started.

You can also export particle systems to alembic, but I haven't tried that yet.

Edit:
You might also want to try to change how the motion blur is calculated in the Render Panel under "Motion Blur" - You can change the calculation from center to end or start of frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try to combine it partwise with the answer of Duane Dibbley. Appreciate you took yourself time to answer my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have not applied anything you should be able to remove the modifiers and keyframes.

Read more on how the animations work, so you can avoid further problems that can arise, for example by the difference in rotation between 0 and 360 degrees.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. I want to render my whole animation backwards, because I have cell fracturing and smoke simulations in it and want to get an "rebuild explosion" effect, so that the debris and smoke collect together until the object is complete again. I can't tweek the keyframe settings to achieve this, so I need to render my scene backwards.

Comment: The next time. Reverse the animation by just invert the "movie" from the render.

Comment: Ok... do you have an idea how to invert the motion blur when I invert my rendered movie/image sequence, as asked in my original question?